# jPanelMenu Not Working

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jpanelmenu

So I'm trying to implement jPanelMenu for my responsive Wordpress site;

www.jaeeunlee.com

I have

```
<div class="menu-trigger">click me</div>
```

in my header, and

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var jPM = $.jPanelMenu({
        menu: '#menu-main-nav-menu',
        trigger: '.menu-trigger'
        jPM.on();
    });
```

in my js file.

I also set the nav ul to display:none when the browser window becomes small.

But when I try to click "click me on the top of the window, nothing happens. My jquery version is 1.7.1.

I'd appreciate your help!

Best,
Jaeeun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation](http://jpanelmenu.com/#usage), I think you need to do something like this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var jPM = $.jPanelMenu({
        menu: '#menu-main-nav-menu',
        trigger: '.menu-trigger'
    });
    jPM.on();
});
```

Comment: One thing is, it works on the computer, but not when I view it on mobile...?

Comment: strange, the documentation website works on mobile and desktop browsers. what type of phone are you viewing your website from? when you go to the documentation site, does their site work?

Comment: try placing this code right below jPM.on(); `$('.menu-trigger').click();`..if that doesn't work, try `$('.menu-trigger').click(function(){});`